# Confidence intervals for binary proportions in a subdivided population

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, binary-data, survey, survey-weights

I am trying to estimate a confidence interval for the population proportion level of a binary (yes / no) variable. The population comes in three segments - easy to sample (I have a sample); hard to sample (I have a sample but it was harder to get); impossible to sample (well, I haven't managed it). [EDIT ADDED:] My sample count of each segment (row sums below) are unbiased estimates of the population segment counts.

So my sample looks like this, where letters are known counts.

```
                Yes       No   Row sum
      Easy        A        B         C
      Hard        D        E         F
Impossible  Missing  Missing         G
```

I would like to assume that the Yes vs. No breakdown is the same for Impossible as it is for Hard, and on that basis calculate a confidence interval for the Yes vs. No breakdown for the population. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Do you know the population proportions of the three classes? Is this survey data, then maybe add tag [tag:survey]

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen, yes the sample segments counts are unbiased estimates of the population sample counts - added to question.